# Self-made Iterator bug

Tags: java, list, linked-list, iterator

I have to make myself a custom linked list, and I have problems with the Iterator. The `next()` method is working correctly, but strangely, the `hasNext()` method does not.
Here is the code:

```
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    final Node<T> currentNode = this.iteratorNode;
    final MyLinkedList<T> list = this;
    final Node<T> firstNode = this.firstNode;

    return new Iterator<T>() {
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            } else if (currentNode == null){
                list.setIteratorNode(firstNode);
                return true;
            } else if (currentNode.nextNode == null){
                return false;
            }
            list.setIteratorNode(currentNode.nextNode);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            if (list.isEmpty()){
                return null;
            } else if (currentNode == null){
                list.setIteratorNode(firstNode);
                return firstNode.data;
            } else if (currentNode.nextNode == null) {
                return null;
            }
            list.setIteratorNode(currentNode.nextNode);
            return currentNode.nextNode.data;
        }
    };
}
```

The components of the code (like the `isEmpty()` and `setIteratorNode()` methods are working correctly. What really makes this weird (in my opinion), is that I basically do the same thing in `next()` as in `hasNext()`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does "Not working correctly" mean?

Comment: It's very bad idea to `set` something in `hasNext` - people expect that  `hasNext` will just provide some information and not changes internal state

Comment: It means it always returns true when iterating trough a list with more than 1 element. Apologies, and I will edit the question.

Comment: And your next() method isn't follwoing the specification for the Iterator interface. Return *null* is not the appropiate action if there is no element, "throw NoSuchElementException()" is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your flaw is that `hasNext` should be idempotent. It should not update the location of the current position. Hence the code `list.setIteratorNode(currentNode.nextNode);` should not exist in `hasNext`

Addition:

Move the variables: `currentNode` and `firstNode` into your `Iterator` class. Make `currentNode` non-final. `currentNode` should be initialized to `null`. The only thing the `Iterator` should modify is its own `currentNode`.

Comment: +1 for your valid point. Although, this isn't the only problem, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the line

```
list.setIteratorNode(currentNode.nextNode);
```

from your `hasNext()` method. You only want to update the position of the iterator in the `next()` method.

Incidentally, I don't like the fact that you seem to store the position of the iterator in the list. This makes it impossible to have two iterators on the same list which have different positions. You should store the position in the iterator itself.

Comment: You are right, it would be better to store it in the iterator. How would you do that?

Comment: @DoraHerbert Anonymous classes can also have member variables. So you can move the `currentNode` variable to your Iterator class.